# Aura component field no longer displaying

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I have the following aura component that has been displaying the record content for external customer community login users.  Sometime during the past few days something has changed & the users aren't able to see the content of the fields anymore.  I verified that the profile has rights to the field.  When logged in as an administrator, I can see the field data in the portal.  Thoughts?

```
<aura:component description="NIIMBL_Project_Details"
            access="global"
            implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="ProjectID" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="showPublications" default="false"  type="Boolean" access="global"/>    
<aura:attribute name="showProjectAbstract" default="false"  type="Boolean" access="global"/>    
<aura:attribute name="showProjectHighlights" default="false"  type="Boolean" access="global"/>    
<aura:attribute name="showWBSSummary" default="false"  type="Boolean" access="global"/>    
<aura:attribute name="showImpacts" default="false"  type="Boolean" access="global"/>    

<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!v.ProjectID}"
                          objectApiName="Project__c">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showProjectHighlights}">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-3">
                <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="Project_Highlights__c" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showProjectAbstract}">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-3">
                <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="Abstract__c" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showWBSSummary}">
        <div class="slds-grid">
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_3-of-3">
                <lightning:outputField variant="label-hidden" fieldName="WBS_Summary__c" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </aura:if>        
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```

Comment: how did you get `v.ProjectID` ?  make sure getting `v.ProjectID` with out null value?

Comment: I take that as input on the component.  I am completely baffled as to how this has been working.  I found that the API name should have been Project2 versus Project. I know I didn't change this.  I am puzzled as to how as a supervisor I was able to see the data even with an invalid API name.  The problem has been resolved, but I don't understand how this was working at all.  Thoughts?

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that it was cached and the API name change occurred. So even though it became invalid you still got the old data served.